# How to use TCPDF with PHP mail function

Tags: php, email, pdf, phpmailer, tcpdf

```
$to = 'my@email.ca';
$subject = 'Receipt';
$repEmail = 'rep@sales.ca';

$fileName = 'receipt.pdf';
$fileatt = $pdf->Output($fileName, 'E');
$attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());

$headers = 'From: Sender <'.$repEmail.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

$message = "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$message .= $attachment.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator."--";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
$action = 'action=Receipt%20Sent';
header('Location: ../index.php?'.$action);
}

else {
$action = 'action=Send%20Failed';
header('Location: ../index.php?'.$action);
}
```

I have been using TCPDF for a short amount of time now to generate PDF files from forms. It works quite well and that part of the PHP has not changed. Now I want to send those PDF files to my email account.

The emailing is actually working with this coding and attaching a PDF. The issue is that it is simply a blank PDF at rough 100 bytes in size. Which of course is not a valid PDF nor does it have anything to do with the responses from the form.

I am really not familiar with the attaching of files to an email in PHP and any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Since it seems like several people are looking at this still I will post my current solution. It involves downloading PHPMailer as suggested below. I have started at the output line for TCPDF.

```
$attachment = $makepdf->Output('filename.pdf', 'S');
SENDmail($attachment);

function SENDmail($pdf) {
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mailer = new PHPMailer();

$mailer->AddReplyTo('reply@to.ca', 'Reply To');
$mailer->SetFrom('sent@from.ca', 'Sent From');
$mailer->AddReplyTo('reply@to.ca', 'Reply To');
$mailer->AddAddress('send@to.ca', 'Send To');
$mailer->Subject = 'Message with PDF';
$mailer->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer";
$mailer->MsgHTML('<p>Message contents</p>'));
if ($pdf) {$mailer->AddStringAttachment($pdf, 'filename.pdf');}

$mailer->Send();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two choices. You can save the PDF to a file and attach the file or else output it as a string. I find the string output is preferable:

```
$pdfString = $pdf->Output('dummy.pdf', 'S');
```

The file name is ignored since it just returns the encoded string. Now you can include the string in your email. I prefer to use PHPMailer when working with attachments like this. Use the AddStringAttachment method of PHPMailer to accomplish this:

```
$mailer->AddStringAttachment($pdfString, 'some_filename.pdf');
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll have to use an external mailing library. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I also wanted to avoid the external mailing library, however it was the perfect solution

Comment: I take my hat off to you davidethell

Answer (score 0):

I tried several alternatives. Only way that worked was when I saved the PDF to a folder and then email it.

```
$pdf->Output("folder/filename.pdf", "F"); //save the pdf to a folder
  require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php'); //where your phpmailer folder is
$mail = new PHPMailer();                    
$mail->From = "email.com";
$mail->FromName = "Your name";
$mail->AddAddress("email@yahoo.com");
$mail->AddReplyTo("email@gmail.com", "Your name");               
$mail->AddAttachment("folder/filename.pdf");      // attach pdf that was saved in a folder
$mail->Subject = "Email Subject";                  
$mail->Body = "Email Body";
if(!$mail->Send())
{
       echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
       echo "Message sent";
} 
echo 'sent email and attachment';
```

Comment: Does your server have the ability to use the `mail()` function? If it does not you will not be able to send mail from `TCPDF`