# Sending PDF File using Phpmailer generated by tcpdf

Tags: phpmailer, tcpdf

i am using PHP mailer to send the invoice in pdf . the pdf is generated using tcpdf plugin attatchment cannot attatched into mail i am using following code 
please help me what can i do ?

```
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');


 $pdf->Output($pdf_name, 'I');

$filename =$pdf_name.".pdf";

$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("invoice.pdf", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

                   require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
                        define('GUSER', 'sagar@example.com'); 
                        define('GPWD', 'xxx'); 
                      $subject ="Instant e-Bill from  for ".$hotel_name; 
                        function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body)
                        { 
                            global $error;
                            $mail = new PHPMailer();
                            $mail->IsSMTP();
                            $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
                            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                            $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
                            $mail->Host ="mail.activebittechnologies.com";
                            $mail->port =25;
                            $mail->Username = GUSER;  
                            $mail->Password = GPWD;           
                            $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
                            $mail->Subject = $subject;
                            $mail->Body = $body;
                            $mail->AddAttachment($attachment); 
                            $mail->AddAddress($to);
                            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                                $error = "Mail error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo; 
                                return false;
                            } else {
                                $error = "Message sent!";
                                return true;
                            }
                        }

                          $message ="Booking enquiry form www.hotelsinkonkan.in";


smtpmailer("hotelinkonkan@gmail.com","billing@hotelinkonkan.com","Invoice Form hotelsinkonkan",$subject,$message);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use TCPDF with PHP mail function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571977/how-to-use-tcpdf-with-php-mail-function)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));
```

PHPMailer takes care of all that for you, so all you need to do is:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($pdfdoc, 'invoice.pdf');
```

Also I can tell from your code that you are using a very old, buggy and vulnerable version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), base your code on the examples provided with it, and read the docs.

Comment: till not attatching the document i the email

Comment: So check the return value, double check that the path to the PDF is correct and that the file is really there.